# Load "Compare Products" in same window Magento

Tags: php, magento

I have a Magento site and I disabled the pop up on the compare file so now it loads in a blank page. What I need is to make the "Compare Products" load in the same page but still keep everything as is (design, menus etc).

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the your custom theme folder

open this file

```
your_custom_theme\template\catalog/product/compare/sidebar.phtml
```

Replace with this button

```
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Compare') ?>" class="button" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_helper->getListUrl()) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Compare') ?></span></span></button>
```

From this button

```
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Compare') ?>" class="button" onclick="popWin('<?php echo $_helper->getListUrl() ?>','compare','top:0,left:0,width=820,height=600,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Compare') ?></span></span></button>
```

Find this and update on your catalog.xml( find this catalog_product_compare_index and change the template name) layout file

```
<catalog_product_compare_index>

    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
    </reference></catalog_product_compare_index>
```

May be it will help you (Note: Don't make changes on the default theme )

Comment: thank you for your answer. The compare file is on base directory. Not theme. But local.xml is inside the theme directory. Which one am I not supposed to touch?

Comment: I just did these changes but still it opens on a blank page and not inside the template :/

Comment: @user2607179 for changes you have to put this file 'sidebar.phtml' inside your theme folder, and make changes in your catalog.xml file as i updated my answer, all i did and tested it is working fine ( ver. 1.7.0.2 ) try

Comment: I am so sorry. Maybe I did not understand something clearly. I changed the button and also changed the reference "root" inside catalog.xml. Then on which directory should I transfer the "sidebar.phtml" and which part of catalog.xml should i change? Are you talking about reference "content"?

Comment: @user2607179 are you using default theme ya your own custom theme?

Comment: I am using a downloaded theme. The compare directory is only available in design/frontend/base/../product/compare and not in design/frontend/mytheme

Comment: @user2607179 for your information that is not theme folder, that is a package

Comment: @user2607179 refer this for batter understanding of package and theme [click here](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7315/creating-a-new-theme/7316#7316)

Answer (score 0):

Copy the sidebar.phtml from the bellow location

```
'app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalog\product\compare'
```

Put it in your new created theme ( theme name according your choice ) ya existing theme in same directroy strature

```
'app\design\frontend\default\your_theme_name\template\catalog\product\compare'
```

change the button as i said my previous answer

Than go to your admin

system --> design --> Add design change --> Custom Design --> select your_theme_name (from the dropdown) save

Find  catalog_product_compare_index from catlog.xml file from your your_theme_name

```
'app\design\frontend\default\your_theme_name\layout\'
```

and change the bellow line code

```
<reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/popup.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
```

to

```
 <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
```

All Done

Comment: So I installed a package cause there is base, default and em. In default there is nothing except the defaults of the 1st installation. I will try to create a new theme from the link you sent me as the only place a compare directory exists is base. I appreciate your time. Thank you

Comment: @user2607179 no no, make changes in your theme folder of your package in same way as i said 'app\design\frontend\your_package\your_theme_name\template\catalog\product\compare'

Comment: oooh.. ok.. I am doing it now and I will let you know Thank you :-)

Comment: my package/mytheme/template/catalog/product does not include any compare directory. So I transfered the one from base. It still though shows comparing on a blank page and not inside the templates body :/

Comment: @user2607179 did you make changes in catalog.xml file inside your package/theme folder?

Comment: yes I did. I changed the page/popup to 1column as you said. It works as for comparing products but it still does not load inside the body of the template. Do I have to change the path of content to something else?

Comment: @user2607179 hi can you make it 2columns-right.phtl and make a debug

Comment: @user2607179 and its working in all layouts but make a debug by changing layouts and let me know

Comment: this made everything blank and it is not restoring :/

Comment: Everything works perfect!! I flushed cache and it worked from base directory as it was! Thank you so much for your time and your help! Honestly I appreciate it! :-)

Comment: I accepted your 1st answer! that was the right one. It just needed a cache flush! :-)

Comment: yes I know! But because I undo everything and did again from the begin your first answer and then flush cache and worked I marked that one as accepted.

Comment: I dont understand if you misunderstood something I said but I want yo thank you again for your help :-)

Comment: @user2607179 its okey :)

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is good but you made a little mistake in the last step.
You said to find catalog_product_compare_index from catalog.xml in the following location:

```
'app\design\frontend\default\your_theme_name\layout\'
```

The correct location is:

```
'app\design\frontend\your_theme_name\default\layout\'
```

If a beginner reads this he wouldn't understand the difference and wouldn't find the file.
I'm a beginner and I was stuck here for a moment.